# Trying to consolidate 2 SQL queries into 1 SQL for better efficiency (if it's possible)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL question. I have a SQL Server database with 2 tables I want to grab data from. It's kind of similar to the database found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

Just the `Customers` and `Orders` table are relevant.

What I'd like to do is use a SQL query to list all of the customers, and below each customer, display all their respective orders.

*Currently* I'm doing something like this (in my classic ASP web page):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

I'm then iterating through all the customers (returned records), and displaying them...but for each record/customer returned, I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustID = " & rs("id")
```

Then iterate through *those* results to display all the open orders for that customer.

Basically it's 1 long page that shows all our 'customers' and each of their open 'orders'.

It's become fairly large/long, and is taking a bit longer than I'd like to load these days.

So again, I'm guessing I could do this more efficiently with a single SQL query to eliminate that 2nd trip to the database for each customer record?

I know didn't give a ton of detail here, but hopefully it makes sense. I didn't want to create a super long post/thread. I can definitely give more details if needed.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Sounds like you want a `JOIN`: `SELECT * FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustID = Customers.id`. I'd recommend against `SELECT *` (so you only grab what you need), but that's the basic gist of it.

Comment: Or just select all customers and all orders (two queries). Thus you have all data available that you need for display. Use `ORDER BY`, so as to have the data ordered as you want it for easy processing.

Comment: Search for "n+1 problem"

Comment: Side note: you clearly have an SQL injection problem, which should be fixed pronto.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little Charlieface? I'm very interested in trying to fix SQL injection vulnerabilities

Answer (score 2):

seems you need  simple join

```
    SELECT c.*, o.*
    FROM Customers c  
    INNER JOIN Orders   o on  o.CustID  = c.id
    ORDER BY c.CustomerName;
```

Comment: is this even valid, every join besides cross needs an ON clause

Comment: I guess the `WHERE` should really be the `ON` for the join condition - no?

Comment: Msg 156 Level 15 State 1 Line 3<BR>
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid retrieving the customer data with each of their orders again and again, you can just run two queries, both ordered by customer name:

### Customers

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY customername;
```

### Orders

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c ON c.custid = o.custid
ORDER BY c.customername;
```